Using Cypress, how can I test that attempting to close a tab results in a confirmation box being displayed?
I want to test that closing a tab (or reloading the tab) results in a confirmation box being displayed. If the user clicks 'cancel', the confirmation box should disappear and the page didn't reload.
I tried to test this with something like this:
cy.on('window:confirm', () => false)
cy.reload()

However, this fails - the page just reloads & the confirmation box doesn't appear. (The confirmation box is definitely working).

Try stubbing the window:confirm and verifying the stub has been called:
cy.window().then((win) =>
  cy.stub(win, 'confirm').as('confirm').returns(false)
)

cy.reload()

cy.get('@confirm').should('have.been.calledOnce')


Here is another work around, that I ever used
describe('Tab close confirmation', () => {
   it('should display confirmation box when attempting to close tab', () => {
     cy.visit('your_page_url'); // Replace 'your_page_url' with the URL of the page you want to test

     cy.on('window:before:unload', (e) => {
     const confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
     e.returnValue = confirmationMessage; // For modern browsers
     return confirmationMessage; // For older browsers
   });

   cy.get('body').type('{cmd}w'); // Close the tab (You can use '{ctrl}w' for Windows)

   cy.on('window:confirm', (text) => {
   expect(text).to.equal('Are you sure you want to leave?');
   return true; // Simulate user confirming the close
   });
  });
});

I may be a good solution for you.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
